# Rails contact form using new HABTM relationship and unregistered users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm new to Rails and I'm attempting to do the following, but I have a feeling I'm not doing it securely:

A visitor to my site can see profile pages for users and contact them without registering. There is a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between users and visitors. When a visitor contacts the user, I want to create a new record in my visitor table with the info they submit and create a new relationship in the users_visitors table so that I can later show the user the submitted info. What I have so far:

**models:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :visitors

class Visitor < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

**views: user/profile.html.erb**

```
#this is at example.com/user/id
<%= form_for Visitor.new, :url => contact_path, :html => { :method => :post } do |f| %>
<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.text_field :email %>
<%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
#this will just point to a confirmation page
post '/contact',  to:  'visitors#contact', :as => :contact
```

I'm lost on two parts: how do I pass/use the user id needed to create the relationship and what should the controller (or model) look like to create this new relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think this route is not the best

```
post '/contact',  to:  'visitors#contact', :as => :contact
```

In my opinion, this `contact` action should be placed on your `Users` controller, not your `Visitors` controller; after all, it's a **`User`** you're contacting, right?

You instead would benefit from a route like *(I'm not using resourcesful routes because I have no clue what the rest of your `config/routes.rb` looks like)*

```
post '/users/:id/contact',  to:  'users#contact', :as => :contact
```

Your `contact` method in your `UsersController` might then look like

```
def contact
  @user = User.find(params[:id]) # this is how you get the user the visitor is contacting

  @visitor = Visitor.create(params[:visitor])
  @visitor.users << @user # this associates the User with the Visitor
end
```

The above should work but is a simplified example *(I'm not handling validation; I'm not redirecting the visitor somewhere after; I'm not actually **contacting** the user)* - You will need to flesh this action out to suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was trying to figure out. I will continue to flesh out the code with validations etc, just didn't want to make someone else do all the thinking :)